# Is there a way to automate the updating of field names in a Custom Expression in Tibco Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have Spotfire dashboards that use Custom Expressions in their visualisations. The name of a database variable was changed at source in SQL Server, so I replaced the column in my information link with the new column name and reloaded my data.

I was given an option to match 'old column name' to 'new column name', which I did.

My problem is that any Custom Expressions that used this 'old column name' have not updated to the 'new column name' in this process, and consequently there are many errors. This column is used in custom expressions for dozens of KPIs and charts, to manually go through them all will be time consuming.

Does anyone know of a way to update a column name so that it will update every custom expression in a dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to programmatically update all of the expressions.  It's frustrating that match columns don't actually update thru all functions in the application.  However, you might try adding in a change column names transformation to change the column name back to the old name, and then your calculations would update.